# Grails accessing nested fields using gstrings

Tags: grails, groovy, gstring

I am trying to access a nested field using gstring but it throws exception groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

I have two classes

```
Class Person{
   Address address
}
Class Address{
  String city
}
```

Somewhere in my code I am doing,

```
def person = Person.get(1)
def field = "address.city"
def city = person."${field}"
```

The line where I am trying to fetch city from person is throwing groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

If I try to fetch a direct property using gstring it works but the above given code doesnt work.

Any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're doing here is trying to access a property by name `address.city` which is equal to  `person."address.city"`, which means that the dot here gets considered as part of property name - not as access separator as you expect. The following code should resolve your property:

```
def city = field.tokenize('.').inject(person) {v, k -> v."$k"}
```

Comment: That is a really elegant solution!

Comment: How do you set value of a nested property retrieved this way?

Comment: @user1200125 This way you retrieve not a property reference, but it's value, so there's nothing to set a value of.

Comment: any idea of how to retrieve propery/field to modify its value then?

Comment: @user1200125 Nope, I'm outta groovying for more than a year now. But you can surely open a dedicated question. I think what you're looking for is reflection.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is with dot operator for access to a subproperty.

This works:

```
class Person{
   String address
}

def person = new Person(address:'Madrid')

def field = 'address'
assert 'Madrid' == person."${field}"
```

---

This works:

```
class Person{
   Address address
}

class Address {
  String city
}

def person = new Person(address: new Address(city: 'Madrid'))

def field = 'address'
def subField = 'city'
assert 'Madrid' == person."${field}"."${subField}"
```

Comment: While I agree that the other answer by Nikita Volkov, def city = field.tokenize('.').inject(person) {v, k -> v."$k"}, IS a VERY elegant answer, I prefer the simplicity and readability of this answer.  At a glance, this answer is clearly understood.